# Incrementally build Docker image hierarchy with Makefile

Tags: docker, makefile

In a project of mine I have several Docker images that base on each others, because I don't need to rebuild basic parts of it every time and just want to incrementally build the upper layers of the hierarchy.

I build the images by means of a Makefile. I do this because I'm admittedly lazy and don't want to enter the whole `docker build` commands manually every time. And also because I want to avoid making mistakes in the process.

What I would like to do now is make `make` able to detect whether a Docker image has to be rebuild instead of Docker itself because for the latter the Docker build context has to be sent to the Docker daemon every time. The image is quite large because it is based on ubuntu:xenial and so the "Sending build context to Docker daemon" always takes a lot of time for each individual Docker image, independently of whether they need to be rebuilt or not.

If `make` was able to detect whether the `docker build` command needs to be executed that would help a lot to speed up the process.

So I would like to know if there's a way for `make` to detect if a specific Docker image needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: What would be the criteria for a docker needing to be rebuilt?  (if it's just a timestamp comparison, then it's simple, otherwise, you could likely create a script in a recipe to conditionally rebuild).   You would need to provide more information for someone to effectively help you.

Comment: The criteria would be any that makes Docker rebuild a layer of a Docker image. If there's nothing to do, every layer that is part of an image will get loaded from the cache and not rebuilt. In that case that all layers could be picked from the cache I would like `make` to be able to just skip the whole docker build command. I'm not sure how Docker detects whether a layer needs to be rebuilt and if it is inevitable to send the build context to the Docker daemon.

Comment: Just a quick disclaimer: I know nothing about docker itself.   But, having said that, can I assume that each docker image is in its own separate directory, and that the dockers do not depend on anything outside of that directory?

Comment: The `touch` command is your friend, here: use it to create (or update the last modification date) of an empty file at the end of each of your Docker build. And declare the dependencies between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

- your docker images are named `dia`, `dib`, `dic`...
- their respective docker files are named `dockerfile.dia`, `dockerfile.dib`, `dockerfile.dic`...
- their corresponding build directories are `./dia.dir/`, `./dib.dir/`, `./dic.dir/`...
- `dia` depends on files `foo`, `bar` in `./dia.dir/`
- `dib` depends on file `cuz` in `./dib.dir/` and the docker image `dia`
- `dic` depends on file `baz` in `./dic.dir/` and the docker image `dib`

you can try something like (not tested):

```
DOCKERIMAGES := dia dib dic
TAGS := $(patsubst %,.%.tag,$(DOCKERIMAGES))
diaDEPS := foo bar
dibDEPS := cuz
dicDEPS := baz

all: $(TAGS)

$(TAGS): .%.tag: dockerfile.%
    docker build -f $< -t $* $*.dir && \
    echo '$* image built' && \
    touch $@

define DEPS_rule
.$(1).tag: $$(addprefix $(1).dir/,$$($(1)DEPS))
endef

$(foreach d,$(DOCKERIMAGES),$(eval $(call DEPS_rule,$(d))))

.dib.tag: .dia.tag
.dic.tag: .dib.tag

clean:
    rm -f $(TAGS)
```

It should rebuild the docker images only if their docker file changed, or the files they depend on in their directories changed, or the docker image they depend on, changed.

Comment: I'm kind of using this solution now, at least got some inspiration from it. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Very nice! Great minds think alike @renaud-pacalet ;) as I wrote a similar recipe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65913861/23023 - not answering the inter-image-dependency problem though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a small tool called [docker-bakery](https://github.com/smartrecruiters/docker-bakery) that analyses structure of `dockerfiles` and enables triggering hierarchical builds when parent image changes.

For example when `dog` image changes the child images can be automatically rebuild.

```
├── alpine-java
│   ├── bird
│   └── mammal
│       ├── cat
│       ├── dog
│       │   ├── dobermann
│       │   │   └── smaller-dobermann
│       │   ├── pitbull
│       │   └── labrador
│       └── horse
└── scratch
    └── fish
```

The invocation in case of `dog` rebuild could as simple as:

```
$/docker-bakery-example> cd dog
$/dog> make build-major-all
...
// docker build of child images
... 
$/dog> make push-major-all
```

Here is an [example project](https://github.com/smartrecruiters/docker-bakery-example) with `dockerfiles` and `make` files that make the usage very convenient.