# Make: dependency on a docker image

Tags: docker, makefile

I'm using a docker workflow to generate some files, based on a given spec file,  with the Makefile being (it's generating a client according to an OpenAPI spec):

```
SWAGGER ?= ${PWD}/swagger.yaml
GENERATOR ?= openapitools/openapi-generator-cli\:latest

generated: Makefile ${SWAGGER}
    docker run --rm --user $$(id -u):$$(id -g) \
    -v ${PWD}:/output -v ${SWAGGER}:/input/swagger.yaml \
    ${GENERATOR} \
    generate -g python -i /input/swagger.yaml -o /output/generated \
```

this works fine, and will rebuild if I modify the input SPEC file.

But it doesn't rebuild when the docker image is changed.

Let's say I `docker build` the image with the same `name:tag` again, but with different code inside, or I use a different tagged version of the upstream image, whatever. This is kind of expected because the Makefile has no knowledge of the docker image's content or modification date. How can I make the Makefile understand the dependency on the docker image ?

- I've tried to `docker inspect` the image to fetch the creation date, but I don't know how to make `make` understand that as a dependency (if the creation date is newer than the output dir, then rebuild)
- I can't just add a dependency on the code inside the docker image, because the docker image might not even have been built from locally available files.

`make` might not be the tool for that kind of thing, maybe there is something else that I could use that understands the docker image dependency.

Comment: Your problem situation is unclear. Post the Make-project structure and Makefile(s).

Comment: Have you tried with `docker run --no-cache` option?

Comment: @MikeKinghan I've put the actual makefile replicating the problem

Comment: In broad terms, save the Docker image's ID to a file and compare.

Comment: @mulg0r you mean `docker build --no-cache?`,

Comment: @triplee, if I save the ID to a file and depend on that file, then the file will always be newer, and the target will always run, won't it ?

Comment: Yeah, you need to implement some simple logic to only update the file when the ID changes. Probably you need to wrap this in a layer or indirection, either by doing `$(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) realtarget` when the ID has changed, or by a shell `if`/`then` snippet.

Comment: Yes, sorry, `docker build --no-cache`

Answer (score 5):

Whether the artifact you depend on is a Docker image or some service/data somewhere else, you need to represent what *you* know about it, in the form of a **regular file**. Because [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) only deals with files. :-)

I'd recommend you define some macro for *"invoke `docker build` **and** save evidence of its success to a marker file with **predictable name**"* so that you can use that to replace all calls to `docker build`, ensure consistent file handling. Full-blown example, assuming `a/Dockerfile` and `b/Dockerfile` exist.

```
# For consistency, the src dirs are named like the images they produce
IMAGES = a b

# Keep "stamps" around, recording that images were built. 
# You could keep them in e.g. a `.docker-buildstamps/*` dir, 
# but this example uses `*/docker-buildstamp`.
BUILDSTAMP_FILE = docker-buildstamp
BUILDSTAMPS = $(addsuffix /$(BUILDSTAMP_FILE),$(IMAGES))

.PHONY: all
all: $(BUILDSTAMPS)

# Pattern rule: let e.g. `a/docker-buildstamp` depend on changes to `a/*` (-but avoid circular dep)
%/$(BUILDSTAMP_FILE): % %/[!$(BUILDSTAMP_FILE)]*
    $(docker_build)

clean:
    docker image rm -f $(IMAGES)
    rm -f $(BUILDSTAMPS)

# Turn `a/docker-buildstamp` back into `a`
define from_buildstamp
$(@:%/$(BUILDSTAMP_FILE)=%)
endef

# Self-explanatory
define docker_build
docker build -t $(from_buildstamp) $(from_buildstamp) 
touch $@
endef
```